# How to dynamically Load API Data on a button Click in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am a starter in React Native. I have an API that dynamically displays the number of levels on a page. Every time the user clicks on the button, I want to fetch an API and navigate to another page. I have defined three on click events for this, but I want to clean up my code and write with the help of one OnClick event.

My levels are as follows

```
//Level1
async Level1() {
    const datavalue = await getResultValue('url1');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Final','getSomething');
}
//Level2
async Level12() {
    const datavalue = await getResultValue('url2');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Final','getSomething');
}
//Level3
async Level3() {
    const datavalue = await getResultValue('url3');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Final','getSomething');
}
```

Each an every level, there is a corresponding API. Is there a way I can achieve it with the help of One OnClick Event?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know React Native, but can't you use something like Promise.all to get all the results in one time, then set those to your state and somehow with `onClick` go to each one using a level counter state or something else?

Comment: how do you get the `level[n]`? `ternary operation` should do the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async navigateToFinalScreen(params){
  data = await fetch(params.url);
  this.props.navigation.navigate(params.screenToNavigate, 'getSomething'); 
}
```

/*   calling This method */

```
 this.navigateToNextScreen(
   { url:"url",
     screenToNavigate:"Final" }
)
```